# Show that the number $z=\sqrt[3]{4}-2i$ is algebraic, that is satisfied a polynomial equation with integer coefficients.

Tags: complex-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Show that the number $z=\sqrt[3]{4}-2i$ is algebraic, that is satisfied
a polynomial equation with integer coefficients.

I thought I could use the Fundamental theorem of Algebra, but it seems to be false.

Is anyone is able to give me a hint how to solve this problem?
According to Wolfram Alpha, the answer is $x^6+12 x^4-8 x^3+48 x^2+96 x+80 = 0$

Comment: Take $i$ to one side, cube it to eliminate radicals, then again take $i$ to one side and square it. That should eliminate everything.

Comment: Both $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]4,i)/\mathbb Q(i)$ and $\mathbb Q(i)/\mathbb Q$ are algebraic field extension, and the composition of algebraic field extensions is still algebraic.

Comment: Notice that $\root 3 \of 4$ is in the ring of algebraic integers of $\textbf{Q}(\root 3 \of 2)$, which is a domain of cubic integers (that is, degree $3$). Specifically, $\root 3 \of 4 = (\root 3 \of 2)^2$. But this is a domain of real numbers only.
 $2i$, on the other hand, comes from $\textbf{Z}[i]$, a ring of degree $2$ containing complex numbers. thus it makes sense that 6 is the

Comment: @DavidR. It makes sense that 6 is the highest exponent in the polynomial Wolfram Alpha gave? I'm only asking because you seem to have posted your comment without completing what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a hint. Start with $$x = \sqrt[3]{4}-2i$$ rearrange and cube both sides $$ (x+2i)^3 = 4 $$ From there you can expand the polynomial and do some similar steps to eliminate the $i$'s.

Answer (score 4):

$$(z+2i)^{3}=4$$ $$i(6z^{2}-8)=4+12z-z^{3}$$ $$[i(6z^{2}-8)]^{2}=-36z^{4}+96z^{2}-64=[4+12z-z^{3}]^{2}=16+144z^{2}+z^{6}+2(48z-4z^{3}-12z^{4})$$ We have $$z^{6}+(36-24)z^{4}-8z^{3}+(144-96)z^{2}+96z+16+64=0$$
So $$z^{6}+12z^{4}-8z^{3}+48z^{2}+96z+80=0$$

Answer (score 3):

If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic, then $a+b$ is algebraic.

We have

$a^3-4 = 0$

and

$b^2 +4 = 0$.